# gitlab 7.7.2 on RHEL 6 ldap configuration

Tags: linux, ldap, redhat, gitlab

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load
main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
label: 'LDAP'
 host: 'ServerLdap'
 port: 389
 uid: 'sAMAccountName'
 method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
 bind_dn: 'uid=***,ou=JeniePortal,ou=applications,***'
 password: 'passw@rd'
 active_directory: false
 allow_username_or_email_login: false
 base: '0=sample'
 user_filter: '' 
EOS
```

I tried uid also instead of `sAMAccountName`.
Still users are unable to authenticate.
Any help please.

Comment: gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info

System information System: RedHatEnterpriseServer 6.6 Current User: git Using RVM: no Ruby Version: 2.1.4p265 Gem Version: 2.2.1 Bundler Version:1.5.3 Rake Version: 10.3.2 Sidekiq Version:2.17.8

GitLab information Version: 7.7.2 Revision: bd98290 Directory: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails DB Adapter: postgresql URL: http://******dcn HTTP Clone URL: http://**dcn/some-project.git SSH Clone URL: git@*******dcn:some-project.git Using LDAP: yes Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell Version: 2.4.2 Repositories:

Comment: gitlab-rake gitlab:check Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

Comment: Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results) Server: ldapmain DN: uid=Fidel Sevillano uid: Fidel Sevillano DN: uid=test tsbuser2343 uid: test tsbuser2343 DN: uid=test tsbuser2341 uid: test tsbuser2341

Comment: i placed dummy values in place of the bind dn / password . when asking the question. as you can see ldap : check works fine . values i am giving are accurate  ?  yes iam not using Active directory .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your actual issue is, but the thing I notice first is that your `bind_dn` is missing the `uid` value-part. The `bind_dn` defines the user that is used to do lookups for the user that wants to log in. When you connect to an ActiveDirectory that should be something like `sAMAccountName=xyz,ou=JeniePortal,ou=applications` and the password should ve that users password. When the ActiveDirectory allows anonymous access you can leave those two parameters blank (`bind_dn=''`)

Comment: AFAIK for AD `bind_dn: 'CN=gitlab,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=com'` and `uid: 'sAMAccountName'`. But he's not on AD judging from the (cleaned up) config.

Comment: ```bind_dn``` is the DN of the user used to bind for an initial search for the user trying to log in. It depends on the setup of the AD but the given ```uid=,ou=JeniePortal,ou=applications``` will definitely not work as there is no uid set. And AFAIK uid is not available on AD. And therefore the ```bind_dn``` should read something like ```sAMAccountName=xyz,ou=JeniePortal,ou=applications``` to allow a user with name ```xyz``` to be used for initial lookups